# Constant Firewall Messages in Console: How can I find the source?

Tags: macos, network

I constantly see messages in Console (coming from `/var/log/appfirewall.log`) that look like this:

```
Aug 21 08:08:39 silverscreen Firewall[97]: Stealth Mode connection attempt to UDP 10.0.1.11:8612 from 10.0.1.2:64755
```

[Click for a longer sample of the log.](http://cl.ly/2V412p3z1X303c130u2h)

So, it seems that some device on my network (10.0.1.2) is trying various ports to connect to my machine (and being refused).

**What tools does my Mac have to help me figure out what this device is and what it's trying to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command "arp -an" will list all the MAC addresses and IP addresses of all the devices seen on the local network.

Once you have the MAC address, you can look it up to determine the manufacturer of the device, which might give you a clue as to which one of your toys is talking to your machine.  One such lookup site is here:

http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/

UDP Port 8612 is sometimes associated with a Canon printer driver.

Comment: Great, thank you! I didn't know about that command.